# I'm using strapi to build an API but findone returns always {}

Tags: javascript, strapi

This is my code

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(receivedProduct));
var dbProduct = strapi.query('product').findOne({ wooSku: receivedProduct.sku });
console.log(JSON.stringify(dbProduct));
```

receivedProduct Output:

```
{
...some json...
"sku": "LUPV-03300-1",
...some json...
}
```

dbProduct output:

```
{}
```

If I check in the admin, there already exists a product with this attribute value:
[image]

What could be wrong?

###############################

UPDATE:

As it returns a promise, it solved using .then() ...
But I dont't understand why is it "undefined" after adding a function call

```
var dbProduct = strapi.query('product').findOne({ wooSku: receivedProduct.sku })
.then(dbProduct => { 
   console.log(JSON.stringify(dbProduct)); 
   saveProductIfNotExists(receivedProduct);} 
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is that you receive an pending promise because this looks like an async task. Then i have took a look at this last example where they use `await` https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/queries.html#custom-queries and yes thats probably an promise. You can try this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(receivedProduct));
var dbProduct = strapi.query('product').findOne({ wooSku: receivedProduct.sku }).then(dbProduct => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(dbProduct));
});
```

Comment: It worked pero as i'm a bit inexperienced with this and find a new issue.
 please, check the update

Comment: @MartinLarizzate because thats an promise. Promises are asynchronouse in javascript. Javascript does not wait till the query is done it continues its execution. When you execute `strapi.query(...)` you are saying "get the result from the database" but while the fetching you continue your execution to the next line. its undefined because the query is still retreiving the data

Comment: @MartinLarizzate thats why we have the `.then()`. When you fetch the data from the database and wait lets say 1 second. when the fetch is successfull it will execute `.then()` if you get an error you can add an ``.catch()` that catches the errors

Comment: Right! But in my new code, I'm calling a function inside .then()

Comment: @MartinLarizzate what is undefined?

Answer (score 3):

you can consider this approach

```
`strapi.query('modelName', 'pluginName')
```

on this [thread the issue is addressed](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3875)

according to a user

> the findOne means to find one by it's ID. If you need to filter for
> anything else I would recommend you use find as that accepts all the
> other filters.